# There is a sort_field in mailchimp api 3.0?

Tags: mailchimp

I am trying to sort my list using mailchimp API 3.0, but its not working.
Here's what I'm doing:

```
$target = 'lists/'.$list_id.'/members?sort_field=members.email_address&sort_dir=ASC'
```

The sort_dir works fine but I can't find anywhere how to use the sort_field properly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[That particular endpoint](http://developer.mailchimp.com/documentation/mailchimp/reference/lists/members/#read-get_lists_list_id_members) does not appear to allow sorting. The [file manager endpoint](http://developer.mailchimp.com/documentation/mailchimp/reference/file-manager/files/#read-get_file_manager_files) does and lists `sort_field` as a parameter.

Comment: In the Get list parameters does not appear the sort_dir, so i figure since the sort_dir works, sort_field could work too. But o well, i guess i have to stick with the 2.0 for sorting my lists.

Comment: Keep in mind that v2.0 is going away at the end of the year, so you may want to work on another solution for that particular problem.

Comment: Without knowing why you need to sort your list, my answer is going to be something like "Don't do that" or "download the list and sort it on your end." Sorting by email doesn't seem all that useful to me most of the time. ¯\_(ツ)_/¯

Answer (score 1):

Man, what a shame. I was hoping to do the same with segment lists.

```
$result = $MailChimp->get('/lists/xxxx/segments?fields=segments.name,segments.id&sort_field=segments.name&sort_dir=ASC');
```

I ended up having to resort the array in PHP.

```
$segments = $result['segments'];
usort($segments, function ($item1, $item2) {
    if ($item1['name'] == $item2['name']) return 0;
    return $item1['name'] < $item2['name'] ? -1 : 1;
});
```